# Make Micro Chart – Harvey Ball size bigger in the sap.m.CustomTile

Tags: sapui5

I would like to get bigger size of sap.suite.ui.microchart.HarveyBallMicroChart nested in the sap.m.CustomTile than is max "L" size:

```
var oChart = new sap.suite.ui.microchart.HarveyBallMicroChart({         
   size: sap.m.Size.L,         
});
```

I would like to stretch out chart to the bottom and right side of the tile. Now it is ([demo](http://jsbin.com/jaguvarabo/1/edit?html,output)):

[image]

Thanks for any hint. I was also playing with the height and width property of HarveyBallMicroChart but nothing changed.

Comment: You could use the property isResponsive: true for the HarveyBallMicroChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poroperty I was looking for was [isResponsive](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.microchart.HarveyBallMicroChart.html#setIsResponsive).